# How to send params using Volley on Android

Tags: android, httprequest, android-volley

I'm developing an application to get and send parameters to a web. The parameters should be sent like these:

```
{
    "params":{
        "app_token":"[[APP_TOKEN]]"
        "custom_id":"[[CUSTOM_ID]]"
    }
}
```

and the code I'm using is these but with no results:

```
String tag_json_obj = "json_obj_req";

    String url = "http://api.endermetrics.com/v1/account/register";

    HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    params.put("app_token", "AbCdEfGh123456");
    params.put("custom_id","android");


        final ProgressDialog pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Cargando...");
        pDialog.show();

        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new JSONObject(params),
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        Log.d("TAG", response.toString());
                        pDialog.hide();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d("TAG", "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                // Ocultamos el mensaje de cargando
                Log.d("TAG", "Error en la petición.");
                pDialog.hide();
            }
        }
        );

        // Añadimos la petición a la cola de peticiones
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq, tag_json_obj);
```

How should I send the parameters?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have a look ant No 4 here -- http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it doesn't work. I override the getParams with the params to send but still doesn't work.

Comment: are you sure its not the other side that has an issue

Comment: Yes because I'm trying to send params using postman and it works :S

Comment: Try sending the params with the URL and use GET on the other side. at least that way you can confirm. Those Android Hive tutorials are sound, and i don't think there's an error in the code. You could go down the bottom of that page and read the comments. maybe someone spotted something

Comment: Finally using StringRequest instead of JsonObjectRequest I pass the parameters, but I pass them like this: 

{"app_token":"AbCdEfGh123456"
 "custom_id":"Android"
}

and I want to send it like:

{
    "params":{
        "app_token":"[[APP_TOKEN]]"
        "custom_id":"[[CUSTOM_ID]]"
    }
}

How could I do these? Thanks!!!